# c# regex parsing

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse data from a very long html content. I am just pasting here the important part I am interested in:

### Technical Details

```
<div class="content">

    <ul style="list-style: disc; padding-left: 25px;">

      <li>1920x1080 Full HD 60p/24p Recording w/7MP still image</li>
      <li>32GB Flash Memory for up to 13 hours (LP mode) of HD recording</li>
      <li>Project your videos on the go anywhere, anytime.</li>
      <li>Wide Angle G lens to capture everything you want.</li>
      <li>Back-illuminated "Exmor R" CMOS sensor for superb low-light video</li>

    </ul>

  <div id="technicalProductFeatures"></div>
```

I need to start parsing from :

```
<div class="content">
```

til

```
<ul
```

and then until

```
</ul>
```

I have tried following regex but it did not work:

```
Regex specsRegex = new Regex ("<div class=\"content\">[\\s]*<ul.[\\s]*</ul>");
```

this gives me nothing..

One other issue is sometimes it has a linebreak and sometimes not between initial div and ul tags like:

```
<div class="content">
<ul style="list-style: disc; padding-left: 25px;">
```

or

```
<div class="content">

<ul style="list-style: disc; padding-left: 25px;">
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Won't someone think of the children?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I think that horse is still twitching just a bit.

Comment: @Filip: Fair point, but I think you need to explain why...

Comment: I really encourage you to read answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Lucasus has clearly spent three minutes searching for that link :)

Comment: `\s` means whitespace in regex. Your `[\\s]*` are only matching strings of whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using regular expressions for this.  It's like trying to fix a tire with a hammer.  The hammer is a good tool, but it's not for everything.

I'd use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It's not clear to me exactly what you're looking to extract.  But I'll assume it's the list items.  So you'd do something like this...

```
var hdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
hdoc.LoadHtml(YourHtmlGoesHere);

var MatchingNodes = hdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/ul/li");
```

As you can see, the syntax for the Html Agility Pack is based on XPATH and is much simpler for this task.  It's also much more robust and something as silly as nested tags or a comment is not going to throw it off.  Those types of things can throw off even the most carefully written regular expression in this scenario.

---

UPDATE

If you were determined to create a quick & dirty regular expression for this, it'd be something like [this](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=fb605444-dab5-475c-aa20-925eeacae6ea)...

```
<div class="content">.*?</ul>
```

Ordinarily the `.*?` part matches anything *except* lines feeds 0 or more times, as few times as possible.  So be sure to use `RegexOptions.Singleline` so that the `.` will match line feeds as well.  This should work for the example you've given, but a commented bit of code with `</ul>` in it could throw it off, or a nested `<ul></ul>` could throw it off as well.

UPDATE #2

This will grab everything between the `<ul></ul>`...

```
(?<=<div class="content">\s*<ul[^>]*>).*?(?=</ul>)
```

Again, be sure to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Comment: I dont have htmlagilitypack loaded also I wanna learn how I can strip that data with Regex. Regex is not the best tool but still I wanna learn how I can do that.

Comment: Based on his description, I think you want `<div class="content">.*?(?=<ul)` and then `<ul.*?</ul>`. It sounds like he wants to pull two result sets out of there.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Your code is good but still does not work. I changed it as [\\s]*(?=<ul) however I parsed only the initial line with this change and the result was: 
<div class="content">

Comment: Steven I am sorry to take your precious time. Your code works but the problem is I need to start parsing after
<div class="content">
<ul style="list-style: disc; padding-left: 25px;">
not after 
<div class="content">
and sometimes there is a line break after <div class="content"> and sometimes there is not.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am trying your update. Once I learn the Regex style, I will use HtmlAgilityPack in my actual code. I installed htmlagilitypack. However, I really need to learn Regex part to for my future projects.

Comment: Steve your updated code worked like a charm I just made some minor changes. However, in HtmlAgilityPack I got a problem. I am using c# and there is no MatchingNodes in c#. Do I need to add using references?

Comment: @Val - No, MatchingNodes is just a variable name.  I declared it as a var, but it's actually of type `HtmlNodeCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

Regex isn't the best tool to parse html (to put it mildly). Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: probably not but I wanna use Regex

Comment: @ValNolav: nobody is stopping you. Just don't expect many people to help you - this site is about helping and answers are _judged_ by their _quality_. That means that many people are not about to spend much time writing tedious answers of lower quality...

Comment: @Val - Why do you want to use regex? If you think it will save you time or effort, it won't. Regex is not the right tool for this.

Comment: I just wanna learn how I can do that. There are many occasions I meet a line break and I wanna parse it with Regex not only with HTML but also in other text files.

Comment: @Matt - What he's trying to do is not impossible; it's been shown several times that regex can be part of an HTML parser, especially for a limited set of HTML. Full-featured regex engines can incorporate recursion, balanced groups, etc. that make parsing HTML at least possible. However, it is an *enormous* headache, and far more complicated than it seems. It's really not something anyone should do in most circumstances.

Comment: @Val - If you want to know how to work with line breaks, or parse non-HTML text, I suggest you submit a different question focusing on what you want to parse. This question is much bigger than those issues, and they are likely to get lost in the furor. We will gladly help you understand regex, but the first step is to have a task that regex is useful for.

Comment: Justin I know a lot of things in Regex but I am poor at line breaks. I used Regex in many codes and did alot of successful parsing both in html and text documents. However, for long time I have really wanted to learn these line breaks and that s why I asked this question and I learned something new with HtmlAgilityPack, I will try to get used to that for my html related projects.